# Handling dependencies in Java projects with Maven and/or Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies

I'm used to dependency management being handled by tools like NPM or Cargo, and when I look at Java I'm unable to see if there's an equivalent tool, or if indeed the concept of dependency management is handled completely differently.

Specifically I'm attempting to integrate the java files from this [github repo](https://github.com/AaronFoltz/java-hackernews).  Should I just use something similar to git submodules and then store it in a dependencies folder in my project repo?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of dependency management tools in java. Take a look at the [maven](https://maven.apache.org/), for example.

Also, you can consider [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) + [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).

Here is the comparison of these 3 options: https://technologyconversations.com/2014/06/18/build-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding `pom.xml` to your project, then read

[Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

it has also modules that will guide you to

[Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

If you are working with IDE that supports multiple modules of the project and sync with the maven then you can simply add a dependency of one module if it's dependent. The IDE will take care of module dependencies.